# How to load all the properties from respective locale properties file

Tags: internationalization, wicket

Is there a way load all the properties from Class.properties/Class_locale.utf8.properties file to Properties object depending the session locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use `java.util.Properties#load(java.io.InputStream)`.

To get the InputStream you can use

```
String resourceName = SomeComponent.class.getSimpleName() + ".properties";
// String resourceName = SomeComponent.class.getSimpleName() + "_" + Session.get().getLocale() + ".properties";
SomeComponent.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
```

There is nothing in Wicket APIs that would give you a complete Properties. The closest are: `org.apache.wicket.resource.loader.IStringResourceLoader`, `org.apache.wicket.resource.IPropertiesFactory` and their implementations.